# http.proxyHost system property is set to null

Tags: java, maven, proxy, hudson, system-properties

Please help me to find out the reason of the following behaviour.

I have two applications running in Tomcat container: my application and Hudson (v2.2.0). Tomcat is started with `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPost=8080` options so that my application uses proxy to access external WebServices.

I have detected the following very strange behaviour of Hudson running a maven build: At some point of time (just before maven is launched), the **http.proxyHost** system property is set to null. Perhaps I am following the wrong trace, by my application (which is deployed to the same Tomcat) crashes as it cannot open the connection and I think this two are relative.

I have installed the custom **ProxySelector** to report when the proxy is reset. It looks like **http.proxyHost** is reset just before maven starts the dependency resolving:

```
15.12 10:13:35 DEBUG [org.CustomProxySelector] Using proxy DIRECT for URL http://repo.internal/nexus/content/groups/development/org/parent/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1. Proxy settings: http.proxyHost=null, ftp.proxyHost=proxy
java.lang.Exception
        at org.CustomProxySelector.select(CustomProxySelector.java:42)
        at org.CustomProxySelector.select(CustomProxySelector.java:38)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:906)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.verifyChecksum(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:708)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:625)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
15.12 10:13:35 INFO  [hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild] using maven 3 3.0.3
15.12 10:16:10 INFO  [hudson.model.Run] common-ops #87 main build action completed: SUCCESS
```

I might be wrong in what is actually happening: Maven should run in separate JVM, but how **CustomProxySelector** which I install to JVM static variable in my project, is visible from Maven JVM? If "parent" JVM and "forked" JVM share the same root classloader then perhaps they share the system properties as well. That means, if Maven build (even temporary) sets **http.proxyHost** to null and my process opens URL as this time, it will fail.

My question is: If above behaviour is a bug in Hudson / Maven? What can be a workaround (except trivial running 2 Tomcat servers).